# insertable=false puts null into my value, but true gives an error (many to many relationship)

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I have 3 tables. Hospitals and doctors. The 3rd table is a junction table of both that contains id,ids of 2 other tables as foreign keys and few other columns. When trying to put record to a junction table I got an error that one of foreign keys have to be set with insertable=false. However when I set it like this then I get that the value can't be null (since my database requires that field).I'm stuck and can't go any further with those 2 errors.

If I manage to avoid those 2 errors then I get an erorr that there is an unknown column in the field list.

Doctors entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "doctors")
public class Doctors implements Serializable {


    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String title;
    private String licenseNumber;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    private String nationality;
    private String speciality;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    private Boolean isATeacher;
    private List<HospitalDoctors> hospitalDoctors = new LinkedList<>();

//consturctors

@Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "Idd", nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
//setters and getters for rest of the fields with @column annotations on getters

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.doctor", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE})
    public List<HospitalDoctors> getHospitalDoctors() {
        return hospitalDoctors;
    }

    public void setHospitalDoctors(List<HospitalDoctors> hospitalDoctors) {
        this.hospitalDoctors = hospitalDoctors;
    }
```

Hospitals entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hospitals")
public class Hospitals implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String country;
    private String town;
    private String street;
    private String postalCode;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String faxNumber;
    private Integer numberOfAmbulances;
    private Boolean helicopterAccess;
    private Boolean teachingHospital;
    private List<HospitalDoctors> hospitalDoctors = new LinkedList<>();
//constructors

@Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "Idh", nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
//getters setters with @column annotations over getters
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.hospital", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE})
    public List<HospitalDoctors> getHospitalDoctors() {
        return this.hospitalDoctors;
    }

    public void setHospitalDoctors(List<HospitalDoctors> hospitalDoctors) {
        this.hospitalDoctors = hospitalDoctors;
    }
```

Junction table entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hospitaldoctors")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.hospital",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Idh")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.doctor",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Idd"))
})
public class HospitalDoctors implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private Integer idH;
    private Integer idD;
    private HospitalDoctorsId pk = new HospitalDoctorsId();
    private LocalDate contractStartDate;
    private LocalDate contractEndDate;
    private String position;
    private Boolean supervisor;
    private Boolean partTime;
//constructors
 @Column(name ="Idhos")
    public Integer getIdH() {
        return this.idH;
    }

    public void setIdH(Integer idH) {
        this.idH = idH;
    }
    @Column(name ="Iddoc")
    public Integer getIdD() {
        return this.idD;
    }

    public void setIdD(Integer idD) {
        this.idD = idD;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    public HospitalDoctorsId getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(HospitalDoctorsId pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Transient
    public Hospitals getHospital(){
        return getPk().getHospital();
    }

    public void setHospital(Hospitals hospital){
        getPk().setHospital(hospital);
    }

    @Transient
    public Doctors getDoctor(){
        return getPk().getDoctor();
    }

    public void setDoctor(Doctors doctor){
        getPk().setDoctor(doctor);
    }
//rest of the setters getters with @Column
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        HospitalDoctors that = (HospitalDoctors) o;
        if(getPk() != null?!getPk().equals(that.getPk()) : that.getPk() != null) return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (getPk() != null? getPk().hashCode() : 0);
    }
```

Junction table Id:

```
@Embeddable
public class HospitalDoctorsId implements Serializable {

    private Hospitals hospital;
    private Doctors doctor;

    @ManyToOne
    public Hospitals getHospital() {
        return hospital;
    }

    public void setHospital(Hospitals hospital) {
        this.hospital = hospital;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Doctors getDoctor() {
        return doctor;
    }

    public void setDoctor(Doctors doctor) {
        this.doctor = doctor;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        HospitalDoctorsId that = (HospitalDoctorsId) o;
        if(hospital != null?!hospital.equals(that.hospital) : that.hospital != null) return false;
        if(doctor != null?!doctor.equals(that.doctor) : that.doctor != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        result = (hospital != null? hospital.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31* result + (doctor != null? doctor.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I expected to be able to add records to junction table in data base in form fields I have foreign keys for hospital and doctors id to put in as well as other fields. Unfortunately I get either error that say to put foreign keys columns idD and idH as insertable, updatable false which leads to null value being passed which gives another error. When I solve those errors I get the error:
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'hospitaldo0_.Idd' in 'field list'when trying to display records nad unknown column Idd when trying to add record (displaying works when Im getting insertable error or null value error. adding never works)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, you need to have a single @ManyToMany relation rather than two @OneToMany relations.

Comment: @ManytoMany works in case having nothing but foreign keys in junction table. If I had foreign key of id from doctors table and foreign key form hospitals table in a junction table hospitaldoctors I could use that annotation, but since I have extra field and primary key as well it's not a solution.